# how improve speed of math.sqrt() with numba jit compiler in python 2.7

Tags: python, performance, jit, numba

I have a complex function that performs math operations that cannot be vectorized. I have found that using NUMBA jit compiler actually slows performance. It it probably because I use within this function calls to python math.sqrt.
How can I force NUMBA to replace calls to python math.sqrt to faster C calls to sqrt?

--
regards
Kes

Comment: try using `numpy.sqrt` instead

Answer (score 4):

Numba already does replace calls to math.sqrt to calls to a machine-code library for sqrt.  So, if you are getting slower performance it might be something else.

Can you post the code you are trying to speed up.   Also, which version of Numba are you using.  In the latest version of Numba, you can call the inspect_types method of the decorated function to print a listing of what is being interpreted as python objects (and therefore still being slow).

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: He technically did answer (Q: "how can I force NUMBA to replace calls..." / A: "It already does")

Answer (score 1):

Numba is mapping `math.sqrt` calls to `sqrt`/`sqrtf` in libc already.  The slowdown probably comes from the overhead of Numba.  This overhead comes from (un)boxing PyObjects and detecting if errors occurred in the compiled code.  It affects calling small functions from Python but less when calling from another Numba compiled function because there is no (un)boxing

If you set the environment variable `NUMBA_OPT=3`, aggressive optimization will turn on, eliminating some of the overhead but increases the code generation time.